# algorithm issue - find the least common subset

Tags: algorithm

a's are objects with multiple "categories", b's, for instance a1 has three cateories b1,b2,b3.
The problem is to, reduce the number of categories (which can grow rather large), into groups that always occurs together. A "largest common subset" thing.

So for instance, given the following data set:

```
a1{ b1,b2,b3 } 
a2{ b2,b3 }
a3{ b1,b4 }
```

We can find that b2 and b3 always comes together..

```
b23 = {b2,b3}
```

..and we can reduce the category set to this:

```
a1{ b1, b23 }
a2{ b23 }
a3{ b1,b4 }
```

So, my issue is to find some algorithm to solve this problem.

I have started to look at the [Longest Common Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem, and it might be a solution. i.e. something like repeatedly grouping categories like this `b' = LCS(set_of_As)` until all categories has been traversed. However, this is not complete. I have to limit the input domain in some way to make this possible.

Do I miss something obvious? Any hints of a problem domain you can point me to? Does anyone recognize any other approach to such a problem.

Comment: You're highly likely correct. LCS definitely is one that would work for the problem at hand. And the **shortest answer to your main question** is **no you didn't miss anything obvious**. Seems like a nice problem though.

Comment: Really, all you'd need to do is run the same pairing algorithm like you did there to get the b23 pair. Repeat it until there is no change to the sets. First run through would make pairs, second run through would make pairs of pairs or pairs of a pair and a single. So you'd have triplets and quadruple recurrences covered then.

Comment: I think that you can improve your performance by say that your categories are ordered. So, if you draw a matrix with all categories x all objects (axb matrix) all you have to do is to find columns that are equals. I know, its pretty big too, but may be faster :)

Comment: Transforming the sets into a matrix and comparing columns is similar to my answer below - but will take more memory and comparing columns will be inefficient unless you sort columns.

Comment: Indeed, your approach seems faster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transform your sets to have sets of b's that include a's:

```
b1 { a1, a3 }
b2 { a1, a2 }
b3 { a1, a2 }
b4 { a3 }
```

Make sure the contents of the new b sets are sorted.

Sort your b sets by their contents.

Any two adjacent sets with the same elements are b's that occur in the same a sets.

Comment: An additional optimization would be to sort the b sets first by length, then by content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with the LCS if you can impose an ordering on the catagories (if not then the LCS algorithm can't recognize {b3, b4} and {b4, b3}).  If you can impose and ordering and sort them then I think something like this could work:

```
As = {a1={b1, b2},a2={b3},...}
while ((newgroup = LCS(As)) != empty) {
  for (a in As) {
     replace newgroup in a
  }
}
```